# getting an error while updating value for text view android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

here is my layout file which is a part of navigation bar header->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawerProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="157dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/linus_trovalds"
        android:src="@drawable/linus_trovalds"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawerEmailId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="linus-tovalds@linux.com"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/drawerProfileImage" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

now in my onCreate method i am trying to change its text but i get an error.

onCreate method code->

```
//change email id in drawer
        val drawerEmailIdValue = "boy@gmail.com"
        val drawerEmailId = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.drawerEmailId)
      drawerEmailId.text = drawerEmailIdValue   //not working for some reason
```

now here is the error->

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eater/com.example.eater.DishList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

can someone help with what is going on?

Comment: findViewById<TextView>(R.id.drawerEmailId) returning null. Because view not created yet... Try in onViewCreated.

Comment: @mordor619 are you using include tag for including your drawer xml into your main xml? and the onCreate is from Activity or Fragment?

Comment: @Bhavin app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" this is for including and i am using onCreate of activity

Comment: @Crebain can u provide the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access the drawerEmailId directly as this is not part of activity's xml instead it's inside navigation view.

```
val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view) // nav_view is id for NavigationView
val email = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.drawerEmailId)
email.text = "mymail@me.com"
```

you can do it like above it will get the email TextView from header view.

Comment: thanks for your appreciation, as @che10 suggested to use ViewBinding  also try that it will make many things easier.